# ssh-agent (PID 11108, closing is required)

Tags: git, uninstallation, git-bash

Please help me close the following:
I want to uninstall git from my windows machine, and I cannot because of the following popup error message:

[image: git]

Answer (score 11):

Try, from a `CMD`, the commands:

```
taskkill /F /PID 11108
taskkill /F /PID 22668
```

You might have to open `CMD` as admin, for the `taskkill` to complete.

---

As commented by [mwtmurphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5422457/mwtmurphy) in the comments:

> An add-on for those using Git Bash when doing this, use `//` instead of `/` to prefix the commands.

So:

```
bash

$ taskkill //F //PID 11108
$ taskkill //F //PID 22668
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly when I opened the CDM on my machine and typed what you said.

Comment: @FatgezimBela Great! Don't forget to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: An add-on for those using Git Bash when doing this, use `//` instead of `/` to prefix the commands. Cheers @VonC

Comment: @mwtmurphy Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.